# How to store data in redis like mysql structure Or search redis data by value

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, redis

I'm beginner for redis development and went through the redis documentation also started to develop application.

My objective is : Need to store few rows(each contains 4 values of data) in a table and then i need to retrieve and delete a specific row by any one of the four fields. This functionality can be archived in MySQL with insert, update & delete queries. I need your Suggestion/help to archive the same in redis also.

I've chosen hash method to store data in redis and as per my learning knowledge used the hash functions bellow.

Syntax used : `$redis->hset("$Index", "$Field", "$Value");`

Data stored in redis :

```
$redis->hset("users", "1_name", "V.Rajesh");
$redis->hset("users", "1_place", "Ponneri");
$redis->hset("users", "1_email", "rajesh1991f@gmail.com");
$redis->hset("users", "1_fr_email", "mailtodillibabu@gmail.com");

$redis->hset("users", "2_name", "Mani");
$redis->hset("users", "2_place", "Ayyaneri");
$redis->hset("users", "2_email", "mani@gmail.com");
$redis->hset("users", "2_fr_email", "mailtodillibabu@gmail.com");
```

Retrieved single data from redis :(By index and field name)
`$redis->hget("users", "1_name");`

But, I want to get name by email:'rajesh1991f@gmail.com'. Please update me regarding this.

Thanks & Regards,

-Dillibabu K

Comment: You should look at the other questions asked already, but basically you'll need to maintain a reverse map as well in order to do lookups by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hashes, you can keep sorted sets for each user property you want to keep.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user_names 1 Nilo 2 Maria
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user_emails 1 my@email.com 2 her@email.com
(integer) 2
```

The score is the user_id, and the member is the property value.

Then, say you want to query by email, you issue a `ZSCORE`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zscore user_emails her@email.com
"2"
```

You can find in PHPRedis how to call these commands.

Now, you have the ID of the user with email `her@email.com`, just issue a `ZRANGEBYSCORE` with the id:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebyscore user_names 2 2
1) "Maria"
```

(Note that it takes two scores, min and max, so you have to type `2` twice.)

Other fellows in this question told you about reverse mapping, that's another option, you can keep duplicated data for querying hashes with `HSCAN`, but it's still duplicating data.

Comment: Hi Niloct, Thanks for your answer. Your answer(solution) solved my problem..:-Dilli)

Comment: In stackoverflow you usually accept the answer by clicking the green check beside the answer. You can upvote it too by clicking the up arrow. Glad you made it!

Comment: I've voted, But it says: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ah you cannot vote yet, but you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks! You see that you gain +2 everytime you accept an answer.